# equivariant Steenrod algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant

From Hu-Kriz "Real-oriented homotopy theory and an analogue of the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence" we know about calculation of $C_2$ - equivariant Steenrod algebra.

Where can I find (if it exists) information about $(C_2)^k$-equivariant version, $k\ge 2$? I guess $k=2$ would be good enough.